# List of dictionary like strings to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of strings, example below. The strings look like a dict but they are not. I would like to create a Dataframe from the following  with the columns Name, Telephone Number, Country, Email Address, Best time to Call.

The list is quite large so I don't know how many column names there are.

```
 ['{Name: Charlie person}',
 '{Telephone Number: 454895656}',
 '{Country:}',
 '{Email Address: charlie@email.com}',
 '{Name: Karen}',
 '{Telephone Number: 1515451645}',
 '{Email Address: karen@aol.com}',
 '{Name: Sally Lastname}',
 '{Telephone Number: 151451465456}',
 '{Country: USA}',
 '{Email Address: SallyLastname@GMAIL.COM}',
 '{Best time to Call: DAYTIME}']
```

This would not be very difficult if they were actually dictionaries but they are not. I tried converting them to dict by using:

```
from ast import literal_eval
for dct in dict_list:
    literal_eval(dct)
```

But that just threw me a syntax error. Any ideas? Thank you.

An abbreviated desired output would be this

```
             Name   Telephone Number        Email Address
0  Charlie Person          215465121    charlie@email.com
1           Karen       265458614566        karen@aol.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went for regular string manipulation (stripping `{` and `}` and splitting by `:`).

then whenever I encounter `key == "Name"` I open a new record, then finally use `pd.DataFrame.from_records` to get the DataFrame

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

dict_list = ['{name: Charlie person}',
 '{Telephone Number: 454895656}',
 '{Country:}',
 '{Email Address: charlie@email.com}',
 '{Name: Karen}',
 '{Telephone Number: 1515451645}',
 '{Email Address: karen@aol.com}',
 '{Name: Sally Lastname}',
 '{Telephone Number: 151451465456}',
 '{Country: USA}',
 '{Email Address: SallyLastname@GMAIL.COM}',
 '{Best time to Call: DAYTIME}']

records = []
for d_str in dict_list:
    key, value = map(str.strip,d_str.strip('{}').split(":", maxsplit=1))
    key = key.title()
    if key=="Name":
        records.append({})
    records[-1][key]=value

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)

print(df)
```

Comment: Very close to what I was going to post.  Well done (-:

Comment: This works in the example I provided but in the actual list i got `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: NOTE: if you have meaningful `{`, `}`, or `:` in you keys/values, it might mess the whole thing up

Comment: @Vink OK, maybe we can go for a little join or something

Comment: @Vink I edited the answer, now `value` will unpack to everything after  the first `:`

Comment: Banggggggg, thank you! I will accept in 1 min when it lets me